# Zend_Framework and adding a prepended 'directory' to the url

Tags: php, zend-framework, zend-route

I have a ZF app and would like to add a 'directory' to the url structure such that the urls are:

http://domain.com/location/show/id/1 -> http://domain.com/app/location/show/id/1

I would like the app to be served from the host root (domain.com) since there are a set of pretty url'd items http://domain.com/promo that get mapped to http://domain.com/promo/show/name/:promo

Is there a way to inject this into the Router somehow?

thx

edit - this would be for all controllers, I was thinking along the lines of first answer but would ideally like to be able to just push something in there in a more straightforward way

Comment: It's a bit difficult to discern from your question but is this for all ZF app URLs or just a subset, limited to one or more modules / controllers?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe the easiest way is to use the Zen_Router to create internal routes in your application (I don't know much about Zend_Router so I can't be more specific), another option is to structure your application using modules, than you could use the _forward utility to move internally between actions and controllers.